# self.parentViewController is valid on first execution, but nil thereafter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some code that builds and displays a viewController inside a navigation controller.  The first time through the `handleDoubleTapRecognizer` everything works as expected.  However, EVERY time thereafter that `handleDoubleTapRecognizer` is triggered, the navigation controller and its content controller, built in the `handleDoubleTapRecognizer` never appear, and instead I get this delightful message in the console...

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7bbafa00> on <iRpImageViewerViewController: 0x80164580> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Also note that [self.view superview] returns nil, so something is totally destroying the connections from this view to its parent.

...

```
@implementation iRpImageViewerViewController
{
    IGGridView *theMainImageGridviewControl;
    iRpImageSet *thePropertyImageSet;
    iRpImageFilmstripViewController *theFilmstripViewController;
    iRpImageAndMedia *initialMediaItem;  // The item to display when first loaded.
    UIImageView *primaryImageMarker;
    UINavigationController *imageEditorNavController;
    iRpImageEditorViewController *imageEditorVC;

}
```

...

```
-(void)handleDoubleTapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
    {
        NSLog(@"Double Tapped on ImageViewerViewController's main image, so opening editor");

        IGCellPath *pathForCurrentCell = [self pathForCurrentCell];
        iRpImageAndMedia *imageAndMediaItem = [thePropertyImageSet objectAtIndex:pathForCurrentCell.columnIndex];

        imageEditorVC = [[iRpImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImageAndMediaItem:imageAndMediaItem];
        imageEditorVC.navigationItem.title = @"Photo Details Editor";
        imageEditorVC.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        imageEditorNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:imageEditorVC];
        imageEditorNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        imageEditorNavController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(imageEditorDone)];
        imageEditorNavController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(imageEditorCancelled)];
        imageEditorNavController.preferredContentSize = imageEditorVC.view.frame.size;

        NSLog(@"%@'s parentViewController is %@",self, self.parentViewController);

        [self presentViewController:imageEditorNavController animated:YES completion:^(void){ }];

    }


-(void)imageEditorDone
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }


-(void)imageEditorCancelled
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: When "handleDoubleTapRecognizer" method calls first time the self is of the window, and that you are calling "presentViewController" method to load  imageEditorNavController, after that UINavigationController is on the top of window hierarchy. That the reason of getting that message.

Comment: So my log statement, just above `[self presentViewController...]` is saying that self has a parentViewController the first time through, but after dismissing the presented image editor in `imageEditorDone`, and the `handleDoubleTapRecognizer` is entered again by another double tap, THIS time, self has no parentViewController.  Why wouldn't the `self dismissViewControllerAnimated` reset everything back to where it was, and self still has it's link to it's containing parentViewController ??

Comment: @SandeepKumar  - Also note that [self.view superview] returns nil, so something is totally destroying the connections from this view to its parent